# How to configure Apache Drill options as env variable?

Tags: java, configuration, environment-variables, apache-drill

I would like to set `drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled` as `true` in system level by starting drillbit.

I can set it during my session like `alter session set`drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled`=TRUE;`, also I am aware of [drill-override.conf](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuration-options-introduction/) file. However, how can I set it by passing an environment variable to my container such as:

```
    drill:
        image: drill/apache-drill
        restart: always
        environment:
            # - DRILL_EXEC_HASHJOIN_FALLBACK_ENABLED=TRUE
            # - DRILLBIT_JAVA_OPTS="-Ddrill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled=true"
            - DRILLBIT_JAVA_OPTS="-Ddrill.exec.options.drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled=true"
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - orlando:/orlando
        ports:
            - "8047:8047"
            - "31010:31010"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please clarify, whether Drill is started in embedded or distributed mode?

For distributed mode, `DRILLBIT_JAVA_OPTS=-Ddrill.exec.options.drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled=true` should work as expected, but for embedded, this variable is not considered and should be used `DRILL_JAVA_OPTS` variable:

```
- DRILL_JAVA_OPTS=-Ddrill.exec.options.drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled=true
```

For more details about variables description, please reffer to https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/distribution/src/resources/runbit#L36

Comment: I am using the embedded mode and getting: `Error: Could not find or load main class "-Ddrill.exec.options.drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled=true"`

Comment: The issue there was with double-quotes in the variable - they are passed as part of the variable value for. It will work either without quotes: 
`- DRILL_JAVA_OPTS=-Ddrill.exec.options.drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled=true`
or when quoting variable name also:
`- "DRILL_JAVA_OPTS=-Ddrill.exec.options.drill.exec.hashjoin.fallback.enabled=true"`
I have updated the answer to reflect it.